# How to fix "TypeError: Sizer.Add(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:" while trying to set background colour

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm building a GUI with wxpython which consists of a button/statictext grid (25 by 25 grid) similar to a color heatmap

I'm encountering an error when trying to set custom color to each individual statictext/button

I have a working array of statictext/buttons and I'm unable to set custom color to individual statictext/button using below code.

```py
sizer = wx.GridSizer(25, 25, 0, 0)
        sizer.AddMany([wx.StaticText(panel,size=(30,30), label='A1',style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER).SetBackgroundColour((255,0,0)),
wx.StaticText(panel,size=(30,30), label='A2',style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER).SetBackgroundColour((255,255,0)),
```

I was expecting that I can use the SetBackgroundColor() to set custom background color to different statictext and button

I'm encountering the following error:

```py
TypeError: Sizer.Add(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  overload 5: not enough arguments
  overload 6: not enough arguments
  overload 7: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  overload 8: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  overload 9: argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it like that.
What you can do is access all of the children in the `panel` like this.

```
children = panel.GetChildren()
for child in children:
    if child.GetClassName() == "wxToggleButton":
        child.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
```

or slightly more long windedly use the same method on the `sizer`

```
children = sizer.GetChildren()
for child in children:
    x = child.GetWindow()
    if x.GetClassName() == "wxToggleButton":
        x.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
```